# Connection String in Excel not allowing anyone but me to refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, connection-string

I've created an excel spreadsheet using data pulled from a SQL query
but I seem to be the only person who has access to it. Since I will not actually be the one using this spreadsheet, it's important that it work for others. This is the error users are receiving when trying to refresh the data:

> Connection failed:
>   SQLState: '28000'
>   SQL Server Error: 18456
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\UserN'.

Is there a way for me to update the connection string in Excel in a way that will (a) read and accept other windows credentials  or (b) store a username/password

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Excel specifically but in general if you create a SQL Login you can use the following format:

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

You would want to lock down permissions on that SQL Login because anyone would probably be able to see it and connect via other methods.